# Testing MAUI Controls with NUnit

Tags: testing, nunit, maui, dispatcher

I'm a beginner with MAUI. I want to test some code in NUnit which creates MAUI Controls.
I reduced the test to the follwoing short one:

```cs
public void MyTest()
{
    Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ListView result = new(ListViewCachingStrategy.RetainElement);
}
```

After that I want to create a List with items which should be displayed. There is no need of using binding, but can be done.

I get the following exception:
`BindableObject was not instantiated on a thread with a dispatcher nor does the current application have a dispatcher.`

I think the right way should be to use a dispatcher. But how should it be done?
If I use the following code it is always null.
`DispatcherProvider.Current.GetForCurrentThread();`
`Dispatcher.GetForCurrentThread();`

Currently the code is called by the NUnit-Test, later should also be called by the app.

Comment: you don't generally unit test UI code

Comment: Sorry, this does not help me. I will test the code, because it generates MAUI Controls from a special input. That can be tested very good bei an unit test framework. And in most cases automated tests are better than manual tests.

Comment: Of course it's valid to test how controls are generated. It's not really a UI test but a test of generating a small piece of the UI. However, I think you have to provide more info for someone to be able to answer you.

Comment: @Charlie Thanks. The test is really only that line of code. I have reduced it to the minimum to fail. There is no dispatcher. I have added the info.

Comment: See open issue https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11236. Also see open issue https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/2416.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks. So it is a known issue and will be done.